# Can I make microwave frozen ready pizza?

Tags: dough, pizza

I would like to make frozen pizzas and heat them in the microwave. I understand that to warm in oven would be better but I don't want to use an oven. I want to make my own frozen ready pizza and heat in a microwave and achieve similar results to heating in oven. Is this possible? Can I do it by adding an ingredient to the dough?

Comment: What do you mean by spoiling?

Comment: By spoiling I mean, usually when heating a frozen ready pizza in a microwave the pizza base may become vey soft of soggy.

Comment: To the OP: it looks like you accidentally created two accounts (sorry if things were confusing!). You should be able to merge them by going here: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts. If you pick "I need to merge user profiles" in the contact form it links you to, you can paste in your two profile urls: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/users/28861/n-parker and http://cooking.stackexchange.com/users/28862/user28862

Answer (score 3):

The secret to microwave pizzas isn't the ingredients (although that might be part of it) ... the real trick is that they have you cook the pizza on top of the box.

The box has a special 'crisping disk' in it which is [susceptible to microwaves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Susceptor) ... it absorbs microwaves, heats up and then either conducts or radiates heat to the food to be cooked.

You *can* buy microwaveable 'crisping trays' or 'crisping pans'.  You can also buy 'crisping paper' which is sold in rolls but only intended for a single use.  Make sure that it *specifically* says that it's for microwave, and for pizza.  (there are ceramic 'crisping trays' to cook bacon in the microwave, and I don't know if they're susceptors, or just to drain away the grease)